Labels In Amcharts Map Not Showing
I am trying to create a map of Florida for a darts league. I am running into the issue where the label is not showing on the maps.  The debug info shows it is passing the info correctly but it never appears.
I would expect the labels to appear over their respective polygons.
This is using amcharts v5 and the maps function.


// Create root and chart
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
    panX: "rotateX",
    projection: am5map.geoAlbersUsa()
  })
);

// Create polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
  am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
    geoJSON: am5geodata_region_usa_flLow
  })
);

polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
  tooltipText: "{name}",
  interactive: true
});

polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create("hover", {
  fill: am5.color(0x677935)
});

// Set color for multiple counties
polygonSeries.events.on("datavalidated", function() {
  var polygons = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.values;
  var countiesToColor = {
    "Polk": {
      fill: am5.color('#e35205'),
      label: "Polk Dart League"
    },
    "Orange": {
      fill: am5.color('#000'),
      label: "Orange Darts"
    },
    "Hillsborough": {
      fill: am5.color('#000'),
      label: "Dirty Ones"
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    var countyName = polygons[i].dataItem.dataContext.name;
    if (countiesToColor[countyName]) {
      polygons[i].set("fill", countiesToColor[countyName].fill);

      // Ensure children is an array
      if (!polygons[i].children) {
        polygons[i].children = [];
      }

      // Add label if data exists for the county
      if (countiesToColor[countyName].label) {
        var label = am5.Label.new(root, {
          text: countiesToColor[countyName].label,
          centerX: am5.percent(50),
          centerY: am5.percent(50),
          populateText: true,
          fill: am5.color('#000'),
          fontSize: 50 // Adjust font size as needed
        });

        polygons[i].children.push(label);
        label.set("zIndex", 100); // Adjust z-index as needed
        // Add more debugging options here, e.g.,
        console.log("Label created for:", countyName);
        console.log("Label:", countiesToColor);
        label.set("visible", true); // Temporarily hide the label
      }
    }
  }
});
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/region/usa/flLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>


<div id="chartdiv"></div>



